# How to set border color of multiple UIView in tableViewCell when the colors are from an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicolor

I am loading some `UIView` in my `tableViewCell`. One of it's property is border color. This colors are stored in an `NSArray` which is `buttonColorArray`. I want to set them in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this :

`ViewDidLoad` :

```
    self.buttonColorArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                              [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:110.0f/255.0f blue:40.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f],
                              [UIColor colorWithRed:77.0f/255.0f green:212.0f/255.0f blue:92.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f],
                              [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:197.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f],
                              [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0f/255.0f green:89.0f/255.0f blue:152.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f],
                              [UIColor colorWithRed:84.0f/255.0f green:171.0f/255.0f blue:237.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f], nil] autorelease];
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
[Cell.expandedCellContainerView.layer setBorderColor:[self.buttonColorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

But I am getting a warning here. As I know border colors are always to be setted as `.CGColor`. So I add this in my method like this :

```
[Cell.expandedCellContainerView.layer setBorderColor:[self.buttonColorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].CGColor];
```

But it's not working. (It is working if I simply add a fixed color here, instead of array)

I also try to add `.CGColor` in my `buttonColorArray`. But still it is not working. If anyone knows the proper way and the reason to use that, please share with me.

A lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIColor has a property CGColor. Just access it and give it to your view border color like this:

```
UIColor * mycolor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[view.layer setBorderColor:mycolor.CGColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `cell.view.layer.borderWidth` property along with the colour to make it work.
Here is an example of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *reuse = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuse];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuse];
}

UIView *v = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 100, 44)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

UIColor *currentColor = arrayOfColors[indexPath.row];
v.layer.borderColor = currentColor.CGColor;
v.layer.borderWidth = 1; // You need to add this line accordingly
[cell addSubview:v];

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[self.buttonColorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].CGColor]; 
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

layer.borderWidth defaults to zero, you may forgot set it.